# I am unable to do to go to the detailed Activity

Tags: java, android

I have a `ListView` with text and image contents from mysql database, now i want when the user clicks the item, it takes him to details of the item, please help.
Here is the code

```
package appvertiser.estate.real.appvertizer.m_UI;

import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import appvertiser.estate.real.appvertizer.R;

public class PicassoClient {

    public static void downloadImage(Context c, String Image1, final ImageView img) {
        Picasso.with(c).load(Image1).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).into(img);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can add a listener on the ImageView. When the user clicks the image it starts the new activity. You can pass details with the intent.

Comment: Just launch an Intent on the onClickListener for the Layout.

Comment: Will please upload entire code?

Answer (score 0):

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
     startActivity(intent);
   } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method, when user clicks the items in a listview. It fetches the details of the selected item details in the listview and then it goes to the DetailsActivity.

```
ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {

        Intent intent = newIntent(getActivity(),DetailsActivity.class);

        String item = listview.get(position);
        intent.putExtra("id", item.getId());
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Below this method it will move to the next activity when the listview is clicked.it does not fetches any details of the selected items.

```
ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {

        Intent intent = newIntent(getActivity(),DetailsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```